# django-rq Redis Client sent AUTH, but no password is set

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, redis, django-rq

I had my django-rq working a few days ago, but I restarted my computer and now it's not working. I can confirm redis is running with:

```
brew services start redis
```

Here is what I try to run to start redis:

```
python manage.py rqworker
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/code/pricecomparison_project/pricecomparison/maps/views.py", line 231, in get_backend_maps
    django_rq.enqueue(tasks.map_diffbots_backend, alexa_site_id=alexa_site.id)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 226, in enqueue
    return get_queue().enqueue(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 327, in enqueue
    at_front=at_front, meta=meta
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 70, in enqueue_call
    return self.original_enqueue_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 66, in original_enqueue_call
    return super(DjangoRQ, self).enqueue_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 277, in enqueue_call
    job = self.enqueue_job(job, at_front=at_front)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 353, in enqueue_job
    pipe.execute()
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3514, in execute
    self.shard_hint)
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 994, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 502, in connect
    self.on_connect()
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 570, in on_connect
    if nativestr(self.read_response()) != 'OK':
  File "/Users/casey/PycharmProjects/green_brick_django/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 642, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Client sent AUTH, but no password is set
```

I had this issue before and following this fixed it:

https://cmupinkypiggy.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/redis-password-after-installing-with-homebrew/

However, the password is still uncommented in /usr/local/etc/redis.conf so now I officially am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason, killing the old redis processes that we're running on the port fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, killing the old redis processes that we're running on the port fixed it.

Comment: can you tell more? what exactly did you do?